# Migrating NextJS to TypeScript: "strict": true NOT working

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am migrating an existing NextJS project to TypeScript and most things seem to be running fine. I npm installed the suggested type files, NextJS produced a default `tsconfig.json` file for me, I'm able to convert my files to .tsx files, and I see normal TypeScript behaviour such as intellisense and hover-for-details.

However, I flipped **"strict"** from **false** to **true** and I'm not getting any errors at all. For example, Implicit "anys" are not underlined at all.

Here's the default tsconfig with the "strict" property flipped.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
        "allowJs": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "strict": true,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noEmit": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "module": "esnext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "isolatedModules": true,
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: That sounds like an editor-specific problem. Which editor are you using?

Comment: Yeah it's a bit unclear from the question, is this setting not recognized by the compiler/linter, or just the editor?

Comment: Have you tried [running the type checker](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) with the `--noEmit` flag?

Comment: What is your typescript version? According to the [tsconfig reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict), the latest, greatest typescript version won’t tolerate implicit any’s in strict mode. But typescript is always evolving.

Comment: Probably a problem with your editor not recognizing the current settings. Could you provide an example of the exact problem? Also, an overview of your directory structure would be helpful, maybe the tsconfig.json is in the wrong directory.